# How To Filter And Sort A Primefaces Datalist In A Datatable?

Tags: java, sorting, filter, primefaces, datatable

I'm using a Primefaces [datatable](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml) to display data from a SQL Server database, where there is a column with a [datalist](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataList.xhtml) as below:

```
<p:dataTable id="dt"
value="#{demandasController.items}"
rowKey="#{item.id}"
var="item"
selection="#{demandasController.selected}"
filteredValue="#{demandasController.filteredDemandas}"
widgetVar="demandasTable">

<!-- some columns ommited -->

    <p:column headerText="#{adeBundle.ListDemandasTitle_executivo}" filterBy="#{uorPosCollectionItem.nomeGuerra.toString()}" >
        <p:dataList value="#{item.uorPosCollection}" var="uorPosCollectionItem" itemType="none" emptyMessage="-" type="ordered" >
            #{uorPosCollectionItem.matricula.toString()} - #{uorPosCollectionItem.nomeGuerra.toString()} - #{uorPosCollectionItem.prefixo.prefixo.toString()}
        </p:dataList>
    </p:column>

<!-- [...] -->

</p:dataTable>
```

[image: datatable column with the datalist]

I want to sort and filter by that column, but it's not filtering and when I try to sort, an Exception is thrown:

```
-java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
```

I've researched and it seems not possible to perform such actions in a datalist; I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559201/use-jquery-to-assign-function-to-primefaces-datalist-children) that I'm not sure if it might help.

Does anyone knows how can I do to filter and sort a datalist in a datatable ?

Comment: Try using lazyloading on the datatable... then you have full control over what you filter and how...

Comment: @Kukeltje, are you absolutely sure that it will be possible to filter and sort a [datalist](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataList.xhtml) if I use lazy loading?

Comment: No you don't sort/filter the datalist, you sort/filter your data that populates the datalist